# WordPress: Map Domain to same site, alternate content

Tags: wordpress

Say I have a WP website at www.example.com ... it has it's own content. But I have www.example2.com and I would like to redirect www.example2.com to the www.example.com WP site, but with slightly different content.

My first thoughts were just to have a totally different WP install for www.example2.com ... but I'm starting to think there might be a way to utilize multisite.

What would be the best solution for something like that?

Comment: How different, and what type of differences?

You could handle the domain name part by checking what the user arrived through - then set some variables and content different from there. (domain-name would have to be exchanged I suppose - so the site responds to just one name - or change a lot)

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking variables... but how does WP deal with URL variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they are going in that direction already :)

[Setting up Wordpress Multi Site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Cpanel and others have already used "easy-installers".. So a new generic install is added with a few clicks. But with multisite there is the advantage to have just one install - although probably a bit hacking here and there :)